# Pros and cons of using shared Value/Array vs Queue/Pipe in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, pipe, shared-memory

I've been slowly learning to use the multiprocessing library in Python these last few days, and I've come to a point where I'm asking myself this question, and I can't find an answer to this.

I understand that the answer might vary depending on the application, so I'll explain what my application is.

I've created a scheduler in my main process that control when multiple processes execute (these processes are spawned earlier, loop continuously and execute code when my scheduler raises a flag in a shared Value). Using counters in my scheduler, I can have multiple processes executing code at different frequencies (in the 100-400 Hz range), and they are all perfectly synchronized.

For example, one process executes a dynamic model of a quadcopter (ode) at 400 Hz and updates the quadcopter's state. My other processes (command generation and trajectory generation) run at lower frequencies (200 Hz and 100 Hz), but require the updated state. I see currently 2 methods of doing this:

- With Pipes: This requires separate Pipes for the dynamics/control and dynamics/trajectory connections. Furthermore, I need the control and trajectory processes to use the latest calculated quadcopter's state, so I need to flush the Pipes until the last value in them. This works, but doesn't look very clean.
- With a shared Value/Array : I would only need one Array for the state, my dynamics process would write to it, while my other processes would read from it. I would probably have to implement locks (can I read a shared Value/Array from 2 processes at the same time without a lock?). This hasn't been tested yet, but would probably be cleaner.

I've read around that it is a bad practice to use shared memory too much (why is that?). Yes, I'll be updating it at 400 Hz and reading it at 200 and 100 Hz, but it's not going to be such a large array (10-ish float or doubles). However, I've also read that shared memory is faster that Pipes/Queues, and I would like to prioritize speed in my code, if it's not too much of an issue to use shared memory.

Mind you, I'll have to send generated commands to my dynamics process (another 5-ish floats), and generated desired states to my control process (another 10-ish floats), so that's either more shared Arrays, of more Pipes.

So I was wondering, for my application, what are the pros and cons of both methods. Thanks!